# The data second column start when the first column ends

Tags: microsoft-excel, php, xml

[Take this question as a reference](https://superuser.com/questions/589782/split-excel-column-with-xml-inside/1224192#1224192)

How can I put the data of the second columns on the first row.
Sorry  for my English

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP? What have you tried? Please describe your question completely, not just referencing another post. Ideally show an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi, i generate a xml with php

Comment: Sorry, i'm new on this, i generete xml from php and it's structure is the same of the link that i reference, when a try to read in excel the data shows bad. Example: The data of first column starts on the first row but the second column dosen't start on the first row, please see the picture in the reference. My question is, how structure of xml i must have to show very well on excel. Sorry again

Comment: You should edit your question and add a specific example, like in the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The XML must have this structure:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<row>
  <record>
    <LUIS_ARANDA_P>JE1022</LUIS_ARANDA_P>
    <TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>LOC*DPLS62</TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>
  </record>
  <record>
    <LUIS_ARANDA_P>PL9051</LUIS_ARANDA_P>
    <TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>LOC*DRCW82</TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>
  </record>
  <record>
    <TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>LOC*GHKD58</TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>
  </record>
  <record>
    <TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>LOC*GXRX71</TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>
  </record>
  <record>
    <TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>LOC*NH5051</TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>
  </record>
  <record>
    <TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>LOC*PP1001</TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>
  </record>
  <record>
    <TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>LOC*TD5071</TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>
  </record>
  <record>
    <TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>LOC*TV6759</TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>
  </record>
  <record>
    <TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>LOC*YC7898</TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>
  </record>
  <record>
    <TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>PP1001</TRANSPORTES_AVELLO_P>
  </record>
</row>`

Comment: If you want your data on the first row you must put the element on the first child, if you want the data of the second row, you must put the element on the first child... if you want your data on n row you must put the element on the n child. Sorry again